# How to use dd to read and write different block sizes

Tags: linux, dd

I am trying to transfer data from a file to another one using `dd`.

Since I invoke `dd` multiple times in a loop, I have to skip a certain number of blocks from the input file and then start copying.
However, in the last iteration the output block size may be different from the previous ones, so I need to set the `ibs` and the `obs` operands with different values and to skip the first *N* `ibs`*-sized* blocks from the input file.

I know that in dd 8.2 this can be done by setting the `iflag=skip_bytes` operand and specifying the exact number of bytes to skip instead of the number of blocks, but that flag is not available in dd 8.4 that I have to use.

So, I tried to do this by setting the `iflag=count_bytes` option and `count` equal to the number of bytes to be copied.

The resulting commands as regards a normal iteration of the loop and the last one are the following:

```
dd if=./ifile of=./ofile iflag=count_bytes ibs=512 obs=512 skip=0 count=512
...
dd if=./ifile of=./ofile iflag=count_bytes ibs=512 obs=256 skip=2 count=256
```

but dd hangs while copying the data. If I force to terminate each iteration I get the following output from dd:

```
// ibs:512  obs:512 skip:0  count:512
^C1+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes (0 B) copied, 9.25573 s, 0.0 kB/s

...

// ibs:512  obs:256 skip:2  count:256
^C0+1 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes (0 B) copied, 5.20154 s, 0.0 kB/s
```

Am I missing something?

EDIT: dd is invoked from the following C code:

```
while (bytes_sent < tot_bytes){     
    unsigned int packet_size = (tot_bytes - bytes_sent < MAX_BLOCK_SIZE) ?
            (tot_bytes - bytes_sent) : MAX_BLOCK_SIZE;

    sprintf(cmd, "dd if=./ifile of=./ofile iflag=count_bytes ibs=%u obs=%u skip=%u count=%u",
            MAX_BLOCK_SIZE, packet_size, sent, packet_size);
    system(cmd);
    bytes_sent += packet_size;
    sent++;
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Are ifile and ofile plain files? *dd hangs* sounds weird because it is an old heavily tested piece of software...

Comment: @SergeBallesta not really, ifile is a plain file, while ofile is a DMA mapped on a character device at `/dev/ofile`. Nonetheless, if I call dd with:
    `dd if=./ifile of=./ofile bs=256 skip=i count=1`
and the total number of bytes to be sent are a multiple of 256 everything works fine

Comment: Do you experiment same problem, if you set of to plain files (1 different for each pass to be able to later control what has been copied)?

Comment: @SergeBallesta no I don't, if I invoke dd from command line with plain file as ofile everything seems to work. I added the C code to the question for clarity.

Comment: I'm confused. skip_bytes and count_bytes do exactly the same thing according to the manual.

Comment: Changing obs for the last packet is useless, dd is clever enough to never copy more than it has read. Normally `dd if=ifile of=ofile bs=512` should be enough. But invoking dd from C code is weird. Why not a mere loop read buffer - write buffer until end of file?

Comment: @RobertJacobs I know that they are quite similar, but count_bytes refers to the number of bytes to be copied, while skip_bytes refers to the number of bytes to skip from the beginning of the input file.
For my purpose it would be better to use skip_bytes, but it is not available in the dd version I am using.

Comment: @SergeBallesta, it sounds weird also for me, but at the moment I can't do normal read and write due to driver issues. As regards the different obs for the last packet, actually it has to be smaller since I can't write more data than the current value `packet_size`, and the input file is not read completely.

Comment: This smells like an x-y problem. You have problems changing the size of packet on last write when 1/ you have no reason to change it 2/ you should not use dd from a C program. My advice is that you should think about what you are *really* trying to achieve (eventually say it here) and wonder whether you have chosen an appropriate tool.

Comment: Ok, I assume that invoking dd through system introduces some latency and prevents overflow on the driver, at least at the beginning. Or at least the first dd calls are successful. You should read the driver specs to know what throughput it can accept or whether it can inform through ioctl calls when it is ready to accept input.  Alternatively, you could try to introduce wait times  but I really do not like what works only by accident... But your **real** problem has nothing to do with `dd`

Comment: I know that my real problem is another one and I am trying to solve it in parallel, but I don't have driver specs so it's not so easy to be solved.
Nevertheless, I still have the problem with dd, also for the first calls, not just for the last one, and the MAX_BLOCK_SIZE it's determined in order to prevent overflow